# How to Retrieve News Feed using Facebook Graph API.?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on WPF application and I want to retrieve News Feed using facebook Graph API so how I can access it also convert into serialize.!

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I had tried with Graph API to  Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                var temp = obj.GetObject("1078733634_2931461360458", dic); but it will difficult to show the data. can you more describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna use Facebook.dll u can download it using Package Manager in Visual studio if u are using C# for example

[NuGet Package here..](https://nuget.org/packages/Facebook/5.4.1.0)

and code may look like this

```
public List<string> Facebook(string query)
    {
       // Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new FacebookAPI();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        string[] arr = new string[5];
        string result = null;
        FacebookAPI api = new FacebookAPI(token);
```

// query is ur search criteria

```
        JSONObject q = api.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="+query+"&type=post");
        foreach (JSONObject item in q.Dictionary["data"].Array)
        {
            if (item.IsDictionary)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String,JSONObject> jso in item.Dictionary)
                {
                    if (jso.Key == "message"/* || jso.Key == "name" || jso.Key == "description" || jso.Key == "link"*/)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            arr[i] = jso.Value.String;

                        }
                        list.Add (jso.Value.String);

                    }
                    else if (jso.Key == "likes")
                    {
                        foreach (JSONObject like in jso.Value.Dictionary["data"].Array)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JSONObject> lik in like.Dictionary)
                            {
                                if (lik.Key == "name")
                                {
                                    result += lik.Value.String;

                                }
                                else if (lik.Key == "id")
                                {
                                    result += lik.Value.String;    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JSONObject> count in jso.Value.Dictionary)
                        {
                            if (count.Key == "count")
                            {
                                result += count.Value.String;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (jso.Key == "from")
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JSONObject> froms in jso.Value.Dictionary)
                        {
                            if (froms.Key == "name")
                            {
                                result += froms.Value.String;
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            /*
            else if (item.IsArray)
            {
                foreach (JSONObject j in item.Dictionary["data"].Array)
                {
                    if (j.IsDictionary)
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<String,JSONObject> x in j.Dictionary)
                        {
                            result += (x.Key + " --- "+x.Value.String);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             */ 
        }
        return list;
    }
```

you can of course change post and query to whatever you want to search in Facebook Graph API

and there is another way to do that using [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and its really easy

hope that will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Mido but I am trying to add this but the FacebookAPI is give me erro I think it is not into the Facebook dll but is there any where then suggest me thanks once again.I am using Facebook dll like this version Facebook 5.4.1.0